# I want to turn ON and OFF an LED with one button (micropython raspberry pi pico)

Tags: micropython, raspberry-pi-pico

Guys Hi could you please help me with my project:

I want to turn on an LED with 2 modes:
1-with button one it should starts and after 5 second it should tun off
2-with button two, it should turn on and stays ON and then if I push Button 2 I want it to be turned  off.
here is my code, I know I should compare different states but I don't understand it, I can use another button, but I like to learn how to use memory.

```
from machine import Pin, Timer
import time
White_LED = Pin(15, Pin.OUT)
button1 = Pin(14, Pin.IN, Pin.PULL_DOWN) 
button2 = Pin(13, Pin.IN, Pin.PULL_DOWN)
def func(pin):
    if button2.value() == 1:
        White_LED.on()
    
while True:
    button2.irq(func)
    if button1.value() == 1:
        White_LED.on()
        time.sleep(5)
        White_LED.off()
```

I could manage o solve it with two functions now, but the problem is that the button2 won't react as fast as it should and I have to push it couple of times to turn the LED, ON and OFF

```
from machine import Pin, Timer
import time

White_LED = Pin(15, Pin.OUT)
Blue_LED = Pin(16,Pin.OUT) 

button1 = Pin(14, Pin.IN, Pin.PULL_DOWN) 
button2 = Pin(13, Pin.IN, Pin.PULL_DOWN)


def func(pin):
    if button2.value() == 1 & White_LED.value()== 0:
        White_LED.on()
    
def func2(pin):
    if button2.value() == 1 & White_LED.value()== 1:
        White_LED.off()

while True:
    button2.irq(func)
    button2.irq(func2)
    if button1.value() == 1:
        White_LED.on()
        time.sleep(5)
        White_LED.off()
```

I did this and it seems it's working:

```
from machine import Pin, Timer
import time

White_LED = Pin(15, Pin.OUT) 

button1 = Pin(14, Pin.IN, Pin.PULL_DOWN) 
button2 = Pin(13, Pin.IN, Pin.PULL_DOWN)




while True:
    if button1.value() == 1:
        White_LED.on()
        time.sleep(5)
        White_LED.off()
    elif button2.value() == 1:
        if White_LED.value()==0:
            time.sleep(2)
            White_LED.on()
        else:
            time.sleep(2)
            White_LED.off()
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you've written your code, you effectively have your `while` loop fighting your IRQ routines. If you just want the two buttons to act like toggle switches, the easiest solution is probably something like this:

```
from machine import Pin

LED = Pin(2, Pin.OUT)
button1 = Pin(14, Pin.IN, Pin.PULL_UP)
button2 = Pin(12, Pin.IN, Pin.PULL_UP)

while True:
    if LED() and not button1():
        print("ON")
        LED(0)
    elif not LED() and not button2():
        print("OFF")
        LED(1)
```

I've tested this code on Wemos D1 Mini running micropython v1.18.

Note that I've configured the buttons as `Pin.PULL_UP`, and the
switches on my board are connected to ground (so pressing a switch
brings the corresponding pin to logic `0`).

---

[image]

Comment: I've edited my code you can check it, it seems it's working

Comment: If this answer has helped solve your problem, please click on the checkbox to the left of the answer to mark it as "accepted". This is both a way of saying "thanks" to the person who posts the answer and a way to let other people know the question has been resolved.